# Create an Alfresco activiti task with activiti:candidateGroups and activiti:candidateUsers at the same time?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have my activiti workflow defined like this:

Start -> TaskA ->TaskB ->TaskA (sometimes) -> End

When taskA is created comming from Start, I want to assing TaskA always to a group.

But sometimes TaskA may be called from TaskB, and in this case, I need to assign taskA to a not predefined list os users or just one user, or to a group (like when the task is called from the Start).

The problem is: how can I define TaskA to support these two needs? Is it possible to specify both activiti:candidateGroups and activiti:candidateUsers and the workflow engine will pick one or the other accordingly to each of them has a value set?

If not, how can I achieve the same goal?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not an un-usual scenario.
You should create a task listener that handles the assignment on the "Assign" event. Set a process variable on entry to Task B and if set, assign Task A to a user, otherwise assign Task A to a group.

Very common scenario.

Comment: And what would happen with activiti:candidateGroups and activiti:candidateUsers at the task declaration level? I would still need to use them? Do you have an example of what you are taling about? thank you!

Comment: You can add an assignee in the model if you want (and will actually need to for the model to validate) but it is simply a placeholder and will be overridden by your Task Listener.

Comment: hello,I was not able to find an example using that event: activiti:taskListener event="assign" Can you show me one? Please note that im using activity embeded in Alfresco. thank you! Hmm it seems it is the assignment event!